# How to get the path of a Blob using its URL from EventGrids BlobCreated event data?

Tags: azure, url, path, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I am using Logic Apps to create a workflow which is triggered every time a new blob is created. As a trigger i handle an EventGrids BlobCreated event. The data in the events body provides me with the full URL of the blob, thus i have a full absolute URL. Next i use `Get Blob Content` action to get the content of the blob. As far as i know this action takes either Blob ID or Path as an input.

Now here is the problem. I'm using `uriPath` function to convert the URL to Path, but it seems as though it doesn't support some characters (for example `^`). Encoding the URL using `encodeURIComponent` doesn't help.

In both cases i get the error:

```
The template language function 'uriPath' expects its parameter to be a well-formed absolute URI
```

This doesn't happen if there aren't any special characters. This seems problematic, as creating blobs with special characters (like `^`) is allowed.

Is there any other way of retrieving the path of the newly created blob? Am i possibly using different template functions than i should? Or maybe there is another way to get the content of the blob without using its path?

Comment: could you share a sample of an event received in your logic app ?? I am surprised that characters such as `^` are allowed in blob path

Comment: Also, it'd be helpful if you share the JSON code of the Logic App action that you have tried so far.

Comment: @Thomas I am adding the blobs via Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. It allows these characters, which results in them being in the `url` field in [data] of the event.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce the error you are mentioning. When blobs with the `^` character as part of the file name were created, the Logic App action could get the Blob content with no issues. Below the code behind the `Get_blob_content_using_path` action

```
        "Get_blob_content_using_path": {
            "inputs": {
                "host": {
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "get",
                "path": "/datasets/default/GetFileContentByPath",
                "queries": {
                    "inferContentType": true,
                    "path": "@{split(triggerBody()?['subject'], '/')?[4]}/@{split(triggerBody()?['subject'], '/')?[6]}",
                    "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                }
            },
```

HTH

Comment: I use this to as my `path` in get blob content action.
`"/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(uriPath(triggerBody()['data'].url)))}/content"`.
The `encodeURIComponent` were added by designer but the problem appears in the `uriPath` function.

Comment: I guess your approach would work, but woultn't it fail if the blob was to be in a folder? I wanted to make it as universal as possible.

Comment: Not sure if you are mixing both `path` members. The upper one is static, while the one under `queries` is dynamic containing the blob path?